# Why can't I assign a variable inside a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Very new to JS here. When I write PHP I have no problem assigning variables inside a function, but inside a JavaScript function it doesn't work. Why?

example:

```
function hello() {

var animal = 'Dog';
document.write(animal);

}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? ... What happens?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". The variable assignment should work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you calling the `hello()` function anywhere? If not, you will not execute the contents of the function and thus, no `write` will happen.

Comment: I tried the same code on a new page and it worked fine, something on the other page must have been interfering.

Answer (score 1):

put this snippet inside your function to check if your function is being called

`alert('snippet');`

If a message box appears, your code should work, but if it does not then the function is not being executed, post some html coding also.